# Unity question on OnTriggerStay() function

Tags: unity, 2d, javascript

I'm currently working on a soccer game.I have a script for the ball that whenever the ball collides as trigger with the goal line,the ball will return to the middle point.But seems like the ball doesn't `Lerp()` back,afterward I tried to check if Unity counts it as collide or not with `Debug.Log("Goal");` but nothing is logged to the console.Please help me with that.Here is the first code:

```
public var smooth : float;

private var newPosition : Vector3;

function Awake ()
{
    newPosition = transform.position;
}

function OnTriggerStay (ball : Collider)
{
    var positionA : Vector3 = new Vector3(0, 0.3, 0);

    newPosition = positionA;

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Here is the second code (after changing to `Debug.Log()`):

```
function OnTriggerStay (ball : Collider)
{
    Debug.Log("Goal");
}
```

Comment: Pause the game when you think there should be a collision and check if the colliders are in the right place.

Comment: Ensure you have a rigidbody connected to at least one of the objects with a collider

Comment: @Ben sorry but I don't understand what you've said

Comment: @Savlon but the rigidbody will make the object to fall down under the affect of gravity

Comment: As old mate said in an answer, you can either turn gravity off or set the kinematic property to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to having a ridgidbody (one must be present for OnTriggerStay to be called at all), you may also want to try different 'collision detection mode' types on that rigidbody. If the ball is moving too fast the default 'discrete' might not be accurate enough to see the ball whizzing by, and if the ball is going too fast then the 'Continues Dynamic' collision detection mode type might be the best option. For more information on the different types of detection modes please see: [Rididbody Collision Detection Mode in the Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need a rigidbody connected to at least one of the objects with a collider (as @Savlon mentioned), but the other issue with gravity can be alleviated by toggling the rigidbody's Kinematic attribute.

Comment: But according to a document on Unity,when I set the kinetic attribute to false,it might also disable the collision checking.Could you tell me if I'm wrong ?